# jQuery Collapsing/Expanding sections

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

***EDIT:*** Updated code

If you visit this site:  http://dream-portal.net

You'll see this image:

[image: Expand and Collapse sections]

I'm unable to get this bit of code working...

```
global $context, $options;
echo '
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- // --><![CDATA[
var oTd;
function collapse_expand(which)
{
    var type = which.substr(2);
    var type_lower = type.toLowerCase();
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Left":
            oTd = $(".tablecol_0").eq(3);
            break;
        case "Right":
            oTd = $(".tablecol_2").eq(0);
            break;
        case "Top":
            oTd = $(".tablecol_0").eq(1);
            break;
        default:
            oTd = NULL;
            break;
    }

    if (!oTd)
        return;

    oTd.slideToggle("slow", "linear", function(){
        var oNum = !$(this).is(":visible") ? 1 : 0;
        var colExp = oNum == 1 ? "Expand" : "Collapse";
        $("#" + type_lower + "side").text(colExp + " " + type);';
        if ($context['user']['is_guest'])
            echo '
                document.cookie = which + "Collapse=" + oNum;';
        else
            echo '
                smf_setThemeOption(which + "Collapse", oNum, null, "' . $context['session_id'] . '");';
        echo '
    });
}';

$show = array(
    'left' => $context['user']['is_guest'] ? empty($_COOKIE["dpLeftCollapse"]) : empty($options["dpLeftCollapse"]),
    'right' => $context['user']['is_guest'] ? empty($_COOKIE["dpRightCollapse"]) : empty($options["dpRightCollapse"]),
    'top' => $context['user']['is_guest'] ? empty($_COOKIE["dpTopCollapse"]) : empty($options["dpTopCollapse"])
);

if (!$show['left'] || !$show['right'] || !$show['top'])
{
    echo '
    function SBVars()
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){';

            if (!$show['left'])
            echo '
                $(".tablecol_0").eq(3).hide();
                $("#leftside").text("Expand Left");';
            if (!$show['right'])
            echo '
                $(".tablecol_2").eq(0).hide();
                $("#rightside").text("Expand Right");';
            if (!$show['top'])
            echo '
                $(".tablecol_0").eq(1).hide();
                $("#topside").text("Expand Top");';
        echo '
        });
    }

    if (!document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", SBVars, false))
        addLoadEvent(SBVars);';
}
echo '

// ]]></script> 

<div style="width: 100%;"><div id="rightside" class="button_submit" style="float: right;" onclick="javascript:collapse_expand(\'dpRight\');">Collapse Right</div><div id="leftside" class="button_submit" style="float: left;" onclick="javascript:collapse_expand(\'dpLeft\');">Collapse Left</div><div id="topside" class="button_submit" style="text-align: center; width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;" onclick="javascript:collapse_expand(\'dpTop\');">Collapse Top</div><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>';
```

It's written in php, but the jQuery code should work, I just can't understand why?  No console errors that I can see.  I just would like it to expand/collapse the sections with an animate effect...  Is this possible?  Ofcourse I am using cookies for guest to set it to remain collapsed if the page gets refreshed.

Do you think I have to use some sort of step within the slideToggle function in order to get a smooth animation?  If so, how?  Really need some help here, please.

Comment: have you tried using animate for testing purposes? is the height set on .tablecol ?

Comment: @AJ Naidas - Yeah, that was my first approach, using animate `height: toggle` and `width: toggle`, but that was even worse.  So I just recently changed it to slideToggle which seems to work better now... but even still the left and right sidebars each have 200 pixels, but they don't slide smooth at all.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, I've tried just about everything...